# What is the purpose of Perforce file ".perforce"?

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

What is the purpose of [Perforce](http://www.perforce.com/) configuration file `.perforce`?  Where may I find a sample file showing its contents?

[Git-p4 Usage](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git-p4_Usage) refers to this file, but I don't have this file in any of my workspaces nor in my home directory and have not seen this file mentioned in any other Perforce documentation.  Does it have any purpose outside of the context of `git-p4`?  Does it apply to both Windows and Unix environments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it is referring to a [P4CONFIG](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/P4CONFIG.html) file.  This is a property file that can set Perforce variables when you are working in the same directory or a sub directory of the config file.  The name of the file is not important because you set the name using the "P4CONFIG" variable.

The config files are very useful if you have multiple clients because you can let the config files manage your environment for you just based on your current directory.

Comment: Good answer!  The git-p4 documentation could be more explicit about the purpose of this file, what it should contain, and how to use it.  It's purpose wouldn't be obvious to anyone who has never used the `P4CONFIG` environment variable.

Comment: Yes.  Or at least refer to it in a way that someone would know that to look up in the Perforce documentation.